# Unable to change border color using Material UI palette color in React.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a custom side Navigation Bar in React.js using MUI components with a right border.

[image: My unfinished side navigation bar.]

```html
const SideNav = () => {
    return (
        <Stack
            sx={{
                bgcolor: 'background.paper',
                borderColor: 'grey.500', //I want to color my border to grey.500
                borderRight: 1,
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                position: 'fixed',
                width: 80,
                height: 1
            }}
        >
            <Stack alignItems="center" spacing={2}>
                <IconButton color="primary" aria-label="delete" size="large">
                    <DeleteIcon fontSize="medium" />
                </IconButton>
            </Stack>
        </Stack>
    )
}

export default SideNav
```

The problem is that I can't change the color of the right border using the Theme color of the MUI (Material UI) system. Even if I set `sx={{borderColor: 'grey.500'}}` it always default to black color. And also this Application executes normally without any error, but the border-color remains default black.

Answer (score 6):

So I just found the solution to this problem! instead of writing `borderColor: 'grey.500'` before `borderRight: 1` you need to write `borderRight: 1` first before writing `borderColor: 'grey.500'`. I have no idea why but it seems that MUI system can't override the border color when there is no border yet.

**The implementation below won't change the border color when you want to change it.**

```html
sx={{
    bgcolor: 'background.paper',
    borderColor: 'grey.500',//This will not override the default color of the border.
    borderRight: 1,
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    position: 'fixed',
    width: 80,
    height: 1
}}
```

**This is how I fixed it and it works as expected.**

```html
sx={{
    bgcolor: 'background.paper',
    borderRight: 1, //You need to write this first...
    borderColor: 'grey.500', //And write this after if you want to change th color.
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    position: 'fixed',
    width: 80,
    height: 1
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like mui needs a few border properties set. With one of them missing, it won't render the border.

these seem
`borderColor`, `borderWidth`, and `borderStyle`

```
     sx={{
        borderColor: 'red',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderWidth: 1,
      }}
```